# How to convert xhtml to xml after screen scraping in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping

How to convert the retrieved xhtml string to xml file? Are there any FCL libraries to do this?

Comment: XHTML is an XML-compliant refactoring of the HTML standard.  So, by definition, if you've retrieved XHTML, you already have it in XML format.

Is there something more specific you want to accomplish?  Switch it to a different XML schema, maybe?  You'll want to look at XSLT for that.

Comment: Exactly what Dathan said. @Dathan, with all those upvotes, you might as well add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Ben's suggestion:

> XHTML is an XML-compliant refactoring of the HTML standard. So, by definition, if you've retrieved XHTML, you already have it in XML format. Is there something more specific you want to accomplish? Switch it to a different XML schema, maybe? You'll want to look at XSLT for that.